# Calculate field based on other field but row below using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator

I've got a point feature class with X and Y coordinates and would like to calculate two new columns for X_end and Y_end, where X_end equals X from the next point (so from the row one down). This is to be able to create lines using the "XY to line" tool. Previously I created the table in Excel, but it would be neat if I could do this in ArcGIS Pro and include the step in a Modelbuilder tool. I tried entering `=R[1]C[-2]` like in Excel, but that's not doing the trick.

This screenshot shows how the coordinates should be copied:

[image: screenshot showing table with result I am aiming at]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comment from FelixIP, I created the following Model to get from my JSON file to a point feature with coordinates and then a line feature preserving the attributes:
[image: screenshot of Model created in ArcPro]